# Manage google maps android map tile cache

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

On the [Google Maps Android API v2 Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start), man can find this:

> android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Allows the API to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area.

is there any way to manage this cache, to know its size, its durability ? Does Google plan to expose any API about it ?